# insert php for array fail

Tags: php, arrays

i have problem. when i submit nothing insert to mysql database. The matric can be same with the different certificate name.Actually, i try used an array but i fail to configure it... please help me

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
fields = 0;
function addInput() {
if (fields != 10) {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br/><input type='text' name='cer[]' size='30' />";

fields += 1;

} else {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />Maximum 10 fields allowed.";
document.form.add.disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post"> 
<div id="text"><p>matric</p> 
  <input type="text" name="matric" size="30" /> 
 <div id="text"><p>Certificate name</p> 
  <input type="text" name="cer[]" size="30" /> 
  <br /> 
 <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add input field" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sumbit"/>
 </div> 
</form> 
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$Matric = addslashes($_POST['Matric']);
$Cer_name = addslashes($_POST['cer[]']);

if(!empty($Cer_name)){
$query = "INSERT INTO certificate (Matric,Cer_name) VALUE ('$Matric','$Cer_name')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error message, and how does the content in `$_POST['Matric']` look?

Comment: wait .. i not put echo for error..

Comment: i put : if ($result)echo 'Add  success';else echo 'Add  failed'; but nothing come out...

Comment: `if ($result) { echo 'Add succes'; } else { echo 'Add failed'; }` ? To see what actually happens you need to enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: addslashes() works only for string http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: still .. nothing happend when i click submit

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_POST['matric']` with a lowercase `m`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess column `Cer_name` in your db table must be of type varchar. And you are try to store complete array. So better way is try to save certificates as comma separated.

```
$Cer_name = addslashes(implode(',', $_POST['cer']));
$query = "INSERT INTO certificate (Matric,Cer_name) VALUE ('$Matric','$Cer_name')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: thanks .. now data can be insert into db.. but when i click add more field the column show in below the button ... and the input that i type in Matric reset.

Comment: @amanmakmur Firstly I can see you have 2 `<div id="text">` with same id which is incorrect. Give them different id's.

Comment: @amanmakmur Glad to help you. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: i have other problem .. insert the image